# How would I move folders older than 12 months to another archive folder in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have over 1000 folders that are older than a year that contain various files like excel and .txt files. I would like to make a vba program in excel that could move these folders to an archive folder location but I am not sure how to write this in excel as I do not have much experience in having vba do things outside of excel. This is what I found from google and it works but it takes the source folder with it and I just need the folders inside it to be moved.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    
    'Path of the folder where files are locted
    SourceFolder = "C:\Desktop\Source Folder"
    TargetFolder = "C:\Desktop\Target Folder\"
          
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Check if source and target folder exists
    If objFileSystem.FolderExists(SourceFolder) = True And objFileSystem.FolderExists(TargetFolder) = True Then
        objFileSystem.MoveFolder Source:=SourceFolder, Destination:=TargetFolder
        MsgBox "Source folder has moved to target folder"
    Else
        MsgBox "Either source or target folder does not exist"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Google for looping through folfer and copy/move subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Move Sub Folders

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Const SourceFolder As String = "C:\Desktop\Source Folder"
    Const TargetFolder As String = "C:\Desktop\Target Folder"
    Dim Sep As String
    Sep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim fdate As Long ' Account for leap year:
    fdate = Date - IIf(Day(Date) <> Day(Date - 365), 366, 365)
          
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FolderExists(SourceFolder) And .FolderExists(TargetFolder) Then
            Dim fsoFolder As Object
            Set fsoFolder = .GetFolder(SourceFolder)
            Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
            Dim n As Long
            For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
                If fsoSubFolder.DateCreated < fdate Then
                    n = n + 1
                    .MoveFolder _
                      Source:=fsoSubFolder, _
                      Destination:=TargetFolder & Sep & fsoSubFolder.Name
                End If
            Next fsoSubFolder
            MsgBox "Moved " & n & " folder(s) to target folder"
        Else
            MsgBox "Either source or target folder does not exist"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this Worked! is there any material that I could read up on online that could help me with actually understanding this code line by line?

Comment: Start here [`File System Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). Also study the other objects shown to the left of the page. When tired or bored, open a new workbook. In VBE enable `Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and in a new sub write:  `Dim fso As FileSystemObject` :  `Set fso = New FileSystemObject` and continue with `fso.` and VBA's intellisense will show you various possibilities.

Comment: Using the way described in the comment, in the solution you would continue with: `If fso.FolderExists(SourceFolder) And fsoFolderExists(TargetFolder) Then` ; `Dim fsoFolder As Folder` : `Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolder)` : `Dim fsoSubFolder As Folder` and later only change to `fso.MoveFolder _` and you'll have a more readable version. This is called `early binding`, while in the code I'm using `late binding` which among others, means we don't need the reference to the library. Off course you being unfamiliar with it, study in 'early binding mode' to get familiar with the subject.